# PCI WiFi not connected

Tags: wireless, pci

```
sudo apt install gcc make build-essential git linux-headers-$(uname -r)
.
.
.
Building for 5.19.0-37-generic
Building initial module for 5.19.0-37-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.19.0-37-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.19.0-37-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8822bu/5.8.7.1~ppa/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rtl8822bu-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtl8822bu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 r8723bu-dkms
 rtl8822bu-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Error occurs even when attempting to remove driver package

---

```
Recommended:
sudo apt remove --purge r8723bu-dkms && sudo apt remove --purge rtl8822bu-dkms
```

Comment: Please provide your OS & release details.

Comment: `apt` is not the correct method to remove a driver compiled and installed with dkms. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Clearly, you should "Consult `/var/lib/dkms/rtl8822bu/5.8.7.1~ppa/build/make.log` for more information." Use any paging tool `less`, `more` or ...